# How to force telerik radDropDownList to show newly added to database?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a `Telerik RadDropDownList` to display The Cities from the table in `database` that gets updated in the background. i want to refresh the `RadDropDownList` whenever the database is updated but I could not find anything helpful.
My code is here:

```
private void radDropDownList3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _result = radDropDownList3.DropDownListElement.Text;
         bool any = radDropDownList3.DropDownListElement.Items.Any(item => item.Text == _result.Trim());
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !any)
        {
            try
            {
                string city = ArToFa(_result);
                using (var bas = new SaleToFreightageEntities())
                {
                    bas.Tariff.Add(new Tariff { City = city });
                    bas.SaveChanges();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(@"item added.");
                tariffBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
                radDropDownList3.Rebind();
                radDropDownList3.Refresh();
                radDropDownList2.Enabled = false;
                _result = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.GetBaseException().Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row"))
                    MessageBox.Show(@"duplicated item!", @"", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Stop, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
                _result = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you try use timer+backgroundWorker to ask db  and if db change update datesource raddropdownlist?

Comment: No, I update the database manually and I want when the database is updated, the radDropDownList show the last inserted object to database at the end of it

Comment: If you update in background db just after that rebind your raddropdownlist.  Share your code.

Comment: let me explain more, I have a 'radDropDownList' with a data-source binding to it, when I search the desired item in list, if the list doesn't contain that typed word, i am pressing 'Enter' , and in ' radDropDownList3_KeyUp' event it will be added to database but i want when it added to database, also the 'radDropDownList' show that item added newly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert this entered text in `RadDropDownList` dynamicly after inserting into your db. You can add `RadListDataItem` to your `RadDropDownList`.
Use this code to achieve this. This item will be added to your control so you not need rebind it, add it only when are you sure the position was added to db.

```
RadListDataItem dataItem = new RadListDataItem();
dataItem.Text = "enteredText";
this.yourDropDownList.Items.Add(dataItem);
```

Also You can resolve Your problem by calling after update db method which get again datasource and put it to dropdownlist.

Comment: your code is working but calling the update method doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

you have a many way
1 . make a timer.on ur database make a field to name _update(true False)
this field be true if have ur database add or update or delete data
and on this timer check this field . if true refresh and reselect data else dont task
2 . can u make a thread . this job too like timer

u must make field bcoz if on timer u be refresh maybe can not select data and all want to refresh .
if u have problem tell me

Comment: I think must be most easier way to do that but i don't know how.